# Awestruct navigation: sort pages by category

Tags: ruby, haml, jekyll, awestruct

What I'm trying to print out is a `ul` of `li`s, each containing all the pages which have a given tag (set in the metadata)

If not familiar with Awestruct, it's similar to Jekyll and page metadata can be accessed as `page.property`, pages are in a `site` object, and can be iterated over with `site.pages.each`

What I would like to achieve is something which looks like this:

```
Category
    Page
    Page
Category
    Page
    Page
```

Here is what I have so far, I've only been able to print the page titles.

```
- site.pages.each do |page|
            %li
              %a{ :href => page.url}= page.title
```

Is there a simple solution that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you rebuild the structure before passing to Haml?

Comment: Not without changing Awestruct, I'd rather not have to do that. I'm trying to work within it's structure but perhaps I will have to write an extension to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I’ve undersood what you want, something like this should work:

```
%ul
  -site.pages.group_by(&:category).each do |category, pages|
    %li
      = category
      %ul
        -pages.each do |page|
          %li
            %a{href: page.url}= page.title
```

This uses [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to create a hash of arrays of pages keyed on the category attribute, and produces a nested list of all the pages in each one.

This will include *all* pages, including thoe without a category, so you might want to filter the pages array first with [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject):

```
-site.pages.reject{|p| p.category.nil?}.group_by(&:category).each do |category, pages|
  ...
```